# Prove that a linear operator is unitary if and only if it’s matrix with respect to an orthonormal basis is unitary

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

My definition of unitary is given a form, $<Tv,Tw>$=$<v,w>$ so form is preserved.

I don’t get why the matrix representation should not be unitary with respect to any basis. And why the theorem is true. I know that the matrix of the form with respect to a given basis can be given by $a_{ij}=<v_i,v_j>$

Please prove the theorem and say what’s different if our basis is not orthonormal. Pls help

Edit: I found this proof but I do not understand it:

[image]

Comment: What's your definition of unitary matrix? Can you see why $\langle Tv,Tw \rangle = \langle v,w \rangle$ implies that $T^* = T^{-1}$?

Comment: My definition of unitary is only $<Tv,Tw>=<v,w>$ for all vectors in our space. Unfortunately I can’t seem to understand how that follows.

Comment: I know that an orthonormal basis refers the form back to the standard hermitian form.

Comment: My definition of unitary matrix is actually $AA^{*}=I$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\beta$ be an orthonormal basis for a vector space $\textsf V$ and let $\textsf T \in \mathcal L(\textsf V)$. Suppose that $\textsf T$ is unitary and let $A$ be the matrix representation of $\textsf T$ with respect to 
$\beta$. Since $\textsf T$ is unitary we have that
$$\langle \textsf T^*\textsf Tv,w \rangle = \langle \textsf Tv,\textsf Tw \rangle = \langle v,w \rangle \quad  \textrm{ for all } v,w\in \textsf V $$
so, $\textsf T^*\textsf T = \textsf I_\textsf{V}$ and also $\textsf T \textsf T^* = \textsf I_\textsf{V}$. Now, since $\beta$ is orthonormal, the matrix representation of $\textsf T^*$ with respect to that basis is $A^*$ (this is why we need that the basis is orthonormal) and $\textsf T \textsf T^* = \textsf I_\textsf{V}$ implies that $AA^* = I$.

I add a proof of the last result concerning the orthonormal basis and the matrix of the adjoint operator. 
[image]

Check it in *Linear Algebra* by Hoffman & Kunze.

Comment: Thanks, I get everything but the part where you say since $\beta$ is orthonormal, the matrix is $A^{*}$. Why is that true? I don’t get why it has to be orthonormal, what happens if it’s not? Why is the matrix of $T^{*}$ with respect to an orthogonal basis is given by $A^{*}$? Great answer by the way.

Comment: I add a proof of this result to my answer. Thanks and your welcome!